# How to store non NSObject derived data

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Custom object (not derived from `NSObject`) to be successfully stored in `NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults` dictionary

I wasn't even able to store a `List` of string items into the dictionary

`NSArchiver` also doesn't work on objects which are not derived from `NSObject`

Is it mandatory to derive objects from `NSObject` ...

Also if an object contains child objects ( which are non-standard ) are they mandated to be derived from `NSOBJECT` as well?

Comment: What kind of data have you then?

Comment: How are you declaring your custom object?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question as `monotouch`, so I guess you expect a `monotouch` answer.

You can wrap your objects as `NSObject`s quite easily. `string`s can be wrapped in `NSString`s. List can be converted to/from `NSArray`s.

```
var nsobject = NSObject.FromObject (myCustomObject);
var string = new NSString ("hello, world");
var array = NSArray.FromStrings ("hello", "world");
```

`NSString` and `NSArray`, are `NSObject`s

Comment: Hi Stephane My Model object contains many items.. what I understood from your proposal is convert model to NSObject while storing, but that would be tedious. Thanks for the info

Comment: Maybe you asked the wrong question then. Maybe your question was "how to persist object with monotouch"? Multiple solutions not requiring NSObjects exists.

Comment: You can also wrap your whole model at once using NSObject.FromObject()